# php get string from json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Friends, how can I get, for example, the "Clear" string from the array below, where dt = 1553828400 in php ? Thanks in advance!

Array https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/hourly?q=M%C3%BCnchen,DE&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way with `file_get_contents()` and a simple `foreach()` loop based your condition where **dt = 1553828400**,

```
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/hourly?q=M%C3%BCnchen,DE&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02'),true);

foreach($response['list'] as $key=>$value){
    if($value['dt'] === 1553828400){
     echo $value['weather'][0]['main'];
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** You can replace `file_get_contents()` with `CURL` which has more control.

Comment: Thanks very much!!!

Comment: Glad it helps you somehow. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Decode to an array, extract the `dt` values from `list` as keys and then access by the key:

```
echo array_column(json_decode($json, true)['list'], null, 'dt')[1553828400]['weather'][0]['main'];
```

Reusable for more values:

```
$list = array_column(json_decode($json, true)['list'], null, 'dt');
echo $list[1553828400]['weather'][0]['main']; // Clear
echo $list[1553828400]['main']['temp'];       // 276.465
```

Comment: Thanks so much 